# How to change the attributes of a .txt file using CSS?

Tags: html, css, text

I've inserted a .txt file in an html page using the object tag. But the text don't keep the parent's attributes. Here's the code: I set color:blue but the text is black.

```
#DESC {
color:blue;}


<div id="DESC"> <object data="document.txt" type="text/plain"></object> </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Including a text file using an `<object>` element is much like including one using an `<iframe>`. You create a viewport within your document which contains an independent document, CSS rules will not be inherited into the sub-document.

In Firefox (and possibly other browsers, but I haven't tested) you can use JavaScript to access the `contentDocument` property of the object (or iframe) and from there access the `body` (some browsers render text files by generating an HTML document representation of them) and modify the `style`.

In general, however, you would be better off including the text as part of the main document and then styling it normally. This could be as part of a static file, some form of server side include or (for the least reliable and search engine friendly approach) using the JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Thanks! So could I for example use the PHP in any way?

Comment: http://php.net/include (or look for `fopen` and `htmlspecialchars` for a more robust approach)

Answer (score 1):

css is only compatible with html

so the answer to your question is - you can not change a text file appearance with css

Comment: Ok, so how can I do it?

Comment: Technically it is possible, in some browsers, like Chrome, which embed the textual content in HTML tags. But it is most likely implementation-dependant...